# A structure to represent an ordered set of disjoint segments

Tags: data-structures

I have an ordered set of disjoint segments

```
S = {[a1 b1] [a2 b2] ... [an bn]}
```

with `b1 + 1 < a2, b2 + 1 < a3`, etc. All numbers are integers.

I am seeking for a data structure to represent that set with an `insert` operation. I know that there's no intersection between the inserting segment `[a b]` and the segments from `S`, but a merge may be needed if `b + 1 = ak` or `bk + 1 = a` for some `k`.

Answer (score 1):

How about a linked list where the value at each node is a pair of integers.
We need a slightly modified `insert` operation, let's call it `insertAndMerge`.

```
def insertAndMerge(segment, head) {
    curr = head;
    // find element to insert after
    while (segment.a < curr.b) {
        curr = curr.next;
    }

    // if bk + 1 = a case occurs, merge with existing element, otherwise insert the new one
    if (curr.b + 1 = segment.a) {
        curr.b = segment.b;
    } else {
        segment.next = curr.next;
        curr.next = segment;
        curr = curr.next;
    }

    // the insertion or merge above could trigger the b + 1 = ak case, necessitating a merge with the element after it
    if (curr.b + 1 = curr.next.a) {
        toRemove = curr.next;
        curr.next = toRemove.next;
        curr.b = toRemove.b;
        delete toRemove;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've left out some corner cases for simplicity but you get the idea.

Comment: Also, in your question as currently stated, it's not clear whether a < b within a segment. If it isn't, the above solution would still be feasible -- but with extra work at each conditional to compare the correct numbers.

Comment: Thank you for the idea, yes, ai <= bi in every segment. The number of corner cases really made me look for an existing soluition. I've currently implemented this with an ordered set with following logic. Insert a segment into the set. Check if it needs to be merged with adjacent, and remove them all. Finally, add a merged segment into the set.